# 1990s Fantasy fiction involving magic runes?

Tags: story-identification, magic, young-adult

This is killing me. When I was young I remember reading this book:

- female heroine
- young adult fantasy fiction
- need to draw? runes in the air or tattoo them to do certain spells
- opening scene young girl doing magic in a garden, runes/magic above her level and I believe her fire ball spell gets away from her and floats around.
- possibly a male character has a hidden island later in the book.

I know its vague, I apologize but my sister and I cannot remember any more than that and after 20 years, the book is lost in our childhood home somewhere.

Comment: My first thought regarding this was Wen Spencer's *Tinker* series, but that was published too late (2003) to be the book you're looking for, and I think only matches the first 3 of three of your points.